# Have a bootstrap row fill the screen height, but adjust dynamicly on resizing the window

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

UPDATE: The css style:

```
height: 100vh;
```

was causing the initial problem below. I was using this so that a specific section of the webpage filled the screen when a 'page-jump' button was clicked. Is there another way to have the section(`div class="row"`)fill the screen, but it was adjust to contain all the content when the window is resized smaller? When using the above style, it fits the screen perfectly but on window resizing, the height stays at 100vh, but the content within the row is adjusted to stack vertically, so it ovefrlows the row height.

INITIAL PROBLEM:

I am trying to use flexbox style in CSS/Bootstrap to vertically align the content within 3 columns, that are within a row.

Here is a js fiddle with the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/coopwatts/fnh4exxs/

The HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <img></img>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <img></img>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <img></img>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for flexbox is something like:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Flexbox works fine for aligning the content but when the window is minimized down to say xs, the content escapes the row and is jumbled all over the place. I'm trying to utilize bootstraps grid system so things look nicely on mobile and laptops so this is an issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something happened with the code format. I will edit this as soon as possible.

Comment: `display: flexbox` is old syntax. Can you create a demo of the issue you are facing?

Comment: I believe this will fix the problem http://jsfiddle.net/4fgkxmg1/1/

Comment: I did change it to flex rather than flexbox, and this are layed out similar to your fiddle. However the issue is still persistent. I have a height set to 100vh, so that the row fills the entire screen, because I am using a page jump in jQuery, and I want it to fill the screen. Could this be the issue(the height style)?

Comment: Here is a fiddle for the issue [link](http://jsfiddle.net/coopwatts/fnh4exxs/) @ManojKumar

Comment: @cwattsdis just change `align-items: center;` to `text-align: center;`

Comment: @Shehary That sends the content to the top of the row, and only prevents it from overflowing the row at the top, the content at the bottom still goes all over. The row needs to expand to fit all the elements in it when they are stacked vertically in a minimized window rather than horizontally on a maximized window

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding the following jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $(".customer-options").css("height", "auto");
}
else if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $(".customer-options").css("height", "");
    $(".customer-options").css("height", "100hv");
}
});
```

Everything is working great, thank you!